# Error Registering Dynamics CRM Plugin

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a plugin project built in C# that contains all of my plugins for Microsoft Dynamics CRM. The existing plugins are working correctly and appear to be updating correctly. However, when I attempt to register a new plugin, I am getting the below error.

The event I'm trying to register is on an entity that already has a `Create` & `Update` event attached.  I've seen some other questions about the `Unable to load plugin type` error, but none of them seem to indicate a specific plugin that can't be loaded. What am I missing here for registering a new plugin?

#### Step Registration Settings

[image: Plugin Registration Settings]

#### Existing Registered Steps

[image]

#### Error

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Unable to load the plugin type: CCSEQ.Plugins.OpportunityPlugins
Detail: <OrganizationServiceFault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ActivityId>f9958fce-2da6-44ce-855e-532e4e8deeac</ActivityId>
  <ErrorCode>-2147204720</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>Unable to load the plugin type: CCSEQ.Plugins.OpportunityPlugins</Message>
  <Timestamp>2018-06-06T20:31:33.3462414Z</Timestamp>
  <ExceptionRetriable>false</ExceptionRetriable>
  <ExceptionSource i:nil="true" />
  <InnerFault>
    <ActivityId>f9958fce-2da6-44ce-855e-532e4e8deeac</ActivityId>
    <ErrorCode>-2147204720</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorDetails xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
    <Message>Unable to load the plugin type: CCSEQ.Plugins.OpportunityPlugins</Message>
    <Timestamp>2018-06-06T20:31:33.3462414Z</Timestamp>
    <ExceptionRetriable>false</ExceptionRetriable>
    <ExceptionSource i:nil="true" />
    <InnerFault>
      <ActivityId>f9958fce-2da6-44ce-855e-532e4e8deeac</ActivityId>
      <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
      <ErrorDetails xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
      <Message>System.IO.FileLoadException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #0DE0CBC1</Message>
      <Timestamp>2018-06-06T20:31:33.3462414Z</Timestamp>
      <ExceptionRetriable>false</ExceptionRetriable>
      <ExceptionSource i:nil="true" />
      <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
      <OriginalException i:nil="true" />
      <TraceText i:nil="true" />
    </InnerFault>
    <OriginalException i:nil="true" />
    <TraceText i:nil="true" />
  </InnerFault>
  <OriginalException i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Libraries.RegistrationHelper.RegisterStep(CrmOrganization org, CrmPluginStep step)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.PluginRegistration.StepRegistrationViewModel.btnRegister_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

---

#### Update 1

Based on Arun's input, I changed the namespace & dll build name for my C# project and rebuilt the project.  I did this so I wouldn't have to unregister my existing plugins and rebuild them from the ground up.  I registered this new assembly using the plugin registration tool.  When I tried to register a new step, I receive the same error as before.  This occurs for all registered Plugins. The example below is one I tried with Activities (specifically appointments), although I also tried this for Opportunities

#### Step Registration Settings

[image: Appointment Registration Settings]

#### Error Message

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Unable to load the plugin type: COHEN.Plugins.ActivityPlugins
Detail: <OrganizationServiceFault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ActivityId>1bf82d05-04d0-4bd0-a3db-87c480cc3c6e</ActivityId>
  <ErrorCode>-2147204720</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>Unable to load the plugin type: COHEN.Plugins.ActivityPlugins</Message>
  <Timestamp>2018-06-07T13:57:24.8030045Z</Timestamp>
  <ExceptionRetriable>false</ExceptionRetriable>
  <ExceptionSource i:nil="true" />
  <InnerFault>
    <ActivityId>1bf82d05-04d0-4bd0-a3db-87c480cc3c6e</ActivityId>
    <ErrorCode>-2147204720</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorDetails xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
    <Message>Unable to load the plugin type: COHEN.Plugins.ActivityPlugins</Message>
    <Timestamp>2018-06-07T13:57:24.8030045Z</Timestamp>
    <ExceptionRetriable>false</ExceptionRetriable>
    <ExceptionSource i:nil="true" />
    <InnerFault>
      <ActivityId>1bf82d05-04d0-4bd0-a3db-87c480cc3c6e</ActivityId>
      <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
      <ErrorDetails xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
      <Message>System.IO.FileLoadException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #FB840294</Message>
      <Timestamp>2018-06-07T13:57:24.8030045Z</Timestamp>
      <ExceptionRetriable>false</ExceptionRetriable>
      <ExceptionSource i:nil="true" />
      <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
      <OriginalException i:nil="true" />
      <TraceText i:nil="true" />
    </InnerFault>
    <OriginalException i:nil="true" />
    <TraceText i:nil="true" />
  </InnerFault>
  <OriginalException i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Libraries.RegistrationHelper.RegisterStep(CrmOrganization org, CrmPluginStep step)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.PluginRegistration.StepRegistrationViewModel.btnRegister_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

---

#### Update 2

I noticed that we have a post-build step that runs the command:

```
mkdir $(TargetDir)merged $(SolutionDir)packages\ILMerge.2.14.1208\tools\ilmerge.exe /out:$(TargetDir)merged\CCSEQ.Plugins.dll /keyfile:$(ProjectDir)customdevelopment.snk $(TargetDir)CCSEQ.Plugins.dll $(TargetDir)Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll $(TargetDir)Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
```

This appears to create a new directory in our output folder called `merged` which contains a version of the dll.  I have tried updating the assembly with this version of the dll, but it errors the same way.  I have tried doing this with both the debug & release versions of our build.

One other thing I tried is I imported the dll as a reference into my project to try to look at the classes/functions provided by the dll. It appears that there aren't any classes/functions in the dll, but I'm not sure if that means anything or not as I'm not that familiar with dlls.

[image: Library Classes]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We discovered that version `9.0.2.3` of the `Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies` was not compatible with our plugins.  We aren't yet sure why this didn't work, but rolling back to version `8.2.0.2` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen when you have a mismatching plugin assembly version. Build the latest code, register the **assembly** (dll), select all the **plugins** & then try to register a new **step**.

I see the plugin name changed from `CCSEQ.Plugins.OpportunityPlugins` to `Opportunity` when you register the step under **Event Handler** value.

Also you mentioned other steps as create & delete but I see create & update. Are you sure you are updating the right plugin?

Verify the plugin project for class files which are plugins listed under assembly, against which you can register steps.

Comment: I've tried these steps and updated my answer...still unsuccessful